# Running, Riding a bike and hard leg workout (each activity being done once time a week): is it sufficient to enhance my cardio?

Tags: running, cardio, bicycling, legs, heart

Monday: I work out legs with horizontal legs press, squat, romanian deadlift, kind of lunges with the tractions assistance machine, legs extensions and legs curl (almost 2 hours, but it's only one time a week). I feel my heart goes very fast with the "lunges" and the squat.

Friday: I run for 30min (low, medium and high intensity phases are alternated), after 1h30 of arms work out with supersets.

Sunday: I ride an exercise bike for 20min (I think I alternate between low, medium and high intensities but whatever I do, it's a lot less intense than the Friday's running).

**My question is:** is it sufficient to enhance my cardio (in other words: will I progress on all these activities, regarding cardio and will my heart get stronger and have less probability to be ill, and my heart-rate get slower)?

If no: should I run twice, or three times a week?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Not a medical professional of any type. With any medical issue questions please refer to a doctor or cardiologist.

Yes, these breakdowns of cardio activity would ultimately increase your ability and range. I would consider timing the splits of your low, medium, and high intensity and then beginning to add more time at high intensity as you become more comfortable with it. You may look to increase time vs. intensity depending on if your goal is explosive sprints or cardio endurance for OCR or distance running.

Your heart will act in a similar manner to muscles that will plateau at a certain weight, then you will increase the weight. The breakouts you described will help you to gain more cardio endurance over time.